# Insert different "glue" to a implode function based on a value preg_match

Tags: php, mysql, match, array-filter, against

I'm performing a search query with MATCH and AGAINST in Bolean Mode, and i have the keywords stored in an ARRAY to show they like a TAGS, when I IMPLODE the array values to construct the query statement it works fine, but i want to preserve the BOLEAN functionality search like "exact match" or other special characters.

Is it possible to insert quotes when the array value comes with a spaces?

```
INPUT: keyword1 keyword2 "exact match" keyword3

Covert to this array:
$keywords = array(
    [0] = "keyword1",
    [1] = "keyword2",
    [2] = "exact match", <-- This came with quotes so is stored as a phrase
    [3] = "keyword3"
);
```

Then i need to convert to SQL statement with implode:

```
$SQL  = "SELEC field WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('";
$SQL .= implode(" ", $keywords);
$SQL .= "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

I Try to use ARRAY_FILTER() but it only discriminates one instead the other:

```
function words($var){
    return preg_match('/\s/', $var);
}

$SQL  = "SELEC field WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('";
$SQL .= implode(" ", array_filter($keywords, 'words'));
$SQL .= "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

//example above only outputs: exact match
```

My goal is to discriminates array value when the value comes with more than two words, the function adds quotes to the value

```
Expected Output:

$SQL = "SELECT field WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2 "exact match" keyword3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Easy answer: Why not just quote all of the values?

Comment: Thanks but i don't think will be the best way because if i use quotes in all words it means that all words must be present and matched exactly, instead of words that doesn't have any additional character could be optional and could or could't be present in the column. That's what i get from MATCH AGAINST manual, but maybe I'm wrong...